# Is there a way to use a progress bar without loops in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to show a progress bar for any macro based on how long it takes to process automatically. I have tried multiple codes and can't seem to get what I want. Not really sure if it's even possible or if I'm formatting this incorrectly? Some macros take up to 2.5 minutes to process like this code below and I just want to be able to see or show someone else what is going on vs myself or someone else think something is wrong with excel.

```
Sub ProgressWithDeleteUnwanted()

    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim pctdone As Single
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim r As Long
    
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    
    
    ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0
    ufProgress.Show
    For i = 1 To lastrow
    
        pctdone = i / lastrow
        With ufProgress
            .LabelCaption.Caption = "Processing Row " & i & " of " & lastrow
            .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
        End With
        ufProgress.Repaint
        DoEvents
        
        
    
    With Worksheets("AT&T Fleet Complete Data")
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1
        'UserForm1.Show
            If .Cells(rw, "G").Value2 < .Cells(rw, "I").Value2 Then
                .Rows(rw).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
    
    
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "I").End(xlUp).row
    
    For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(r, "I") = 0 Then
    Rows(r).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next r
    
     'Resource/Crew
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    Worksheets("AT&T Fleet Complete Data").Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Table4[[Asset]:[Resource/Crew]],2,0),0)"
     
        If i = lastrow Then Unload ufProgress
    Next i
    
    Calculate

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "progress bars without loops"? If there is no `For` loop which takes a long time to process, how do you intend to measure progress? It is usually measured by the percentage of total loop iterations that have finished. In any event, progress bars are seldom completely satisfying since it is typically difficult to impossible to know how much time remains.

Comment: Yeah, I know that question came off not making sense. I guess I am wondering if there is a way to setup a progress bar using time vs loops to let the audience know that the macro is being ran and processing during a period of time and that the progress bar will then close once the macro has processed?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use something called 'ApplicationStatusBar'.

[image]

Here's an example

```
Sub DisplayMessageOnStatusBar()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = "Calling function one "

' call function_1

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:2"))
Application.StatusBar = "Calling function two"

'Call function_2

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:2"))
Application.StatusBar = "Calling function Three"

'Call function_3

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:2"))
Application.StatusBar = ""

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

See the links below for more info.

https://www.exceltip.com/menus-toolbars-status-bar-in-vba/display-a-message-on-the-statusbar-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/statusbar.html